# Ubuntu 22.04 LTS randomly stops working

Tags: 22.04, freeze, cpu

I have a headless install of Ubuntu 22.04 LTS on a desktop that I'm using as a server and it will occasionally stop working. I can't determine what causes it as it happens both when the server is idle and when I'm using it and never after the same amount of time.
When this happens I can no longer ssh into or ping the server and when I have a display plugged into it it simply stops responding to my inputs. I can type in the console but it doesn't do anything with said input. I've had this issue for a while and have tried various fixes and even tried reinstalling Ubuntu.
Whenever I restart the server with the power button and I ssh into the machine and check the logs I don't see anything out of the ordinary and the logs just simply stop after the time that it shutdown. I've done a memory test and that came back with no errors.

My computer specs are:

```
Mobo: Gigabyte A320M-S2H
CPU: Ryzen 5 1600
HDD: Seagate Ironwolf 4TB
GPU: GeForce GT 710 RAM: 8GB DDR4
```

**UPDATE:**

After making sure my hard drive is alright I swapped out my PSU and still had the same issue... HOWEVER I noticed that after changing my PSU and checking journalctl I noticed I had LOGS of an ISSUE!!! Whether this is purely a coincidence or if changing my power supply actually changed/fixed something is a mystery to me (It's possible that this is actually another issue added on top of my original problem).

(Note: During the time between the original post date and this update I installed a graphical environment for testing with streaming games from my gaming computer to my tv. It doesn't start on default and has to be started with a script though. Probably not the best idea to make big changes like this while debugging issues but what's done is done lol)

Heres the portion of the kernal output. Full output can be found in [this](https://pastebin.com/F3frtv4j) pastebin.

```
journalctl -k 
Aug 16 03:20:34 foxden-server kernel: NMI watchdog: Watchdog detected hard LOCKUP on cpu 1
Aug 16 03:20:34 foxden-server kernel: Modules linked in: tls rfcomm xt_connmark xt_mark iptable_mangle xt_comment iptable_raw iptable_nat wireguard curve25519_x86_64 libchacha20poly1305 chacha_x86_64 poly1305_x86_64 libblake2s blake2s_x86_64 libcurve25519_generic libchacha libblake2s_generic ip6_udp_tunnel udp_tunnel iptable_filter bpfilter xt_nat xt_tcpudp veth xt_conntrack nft_chain_nat xt_MASQUERADE nf_nat nf_conntrack_netlink nf_conntrack nf_defrag_ipv6 nf_defrag_ipv4 xfrm_user xfrm_algo nft_counter xt_addrtype nft_compat nf_tables nfnetlink br_netfilter bridge stp llc cmac algif_hash algif_skcipher af_alg bnep overlay nls_iso8859_1 snd_hda_codec_realtek snd_hda_codec_generic intel_rapl_msr intel_rapl_common snd_hda_codec_hdmi ledtrig_audio snd_hda_intel snd_intel_dspcfg snd_intel_sdw_acpi edac_mce_amd snd_hda_codec kvm_amd snd_hda_core snd_hwdep btusb nvidiafb snd_pcm btrtl btbcm btintel snd_timer snd bluetooth ecdh_generic ecc soundcore k10temp nvidia_uvm(POE) vgastate ccp fb_ddc i2c_algo_bit kvm rapl
Aug 16 03:20:34 foxden-server kernel:  gigabyte_wmi wmi_bmof mac_hid sch_fq_codel ledtrig_timer ipmi_devintf dm_multipath ipmi_msghandler scsi_dh_rdac mtd scsi_dh_emc scsi_dh_alua msr efi_pstore ramoops pstore_blk reed_solomon pstore_zone ip_tables x_tables autofs4 btrfs blake2b_generic zstd_compress raid10 raid456 async_raid6_recov async_memcpy async_pq async_xor async_tx xor raid6_pq libcrc32c raid1 raid0 multipath linear nvidia_drm(POE) nvidia_modeset(POE) nvidia(POE) drm_kms_helper syscopyarea crct10dif_pclmul sysfillrect crc32_pclmul sysimgblt ghash_clmulni_intel fb_sys_fops cec aesni_intel rc_core crypto_simd r8169 ahci xhci_pci gpio_amdpt cryptd drm i2c_piix4 realtek libahci xhci_pci_renesas wmi gpio_generic
Aug 16 03:20:34 foxden-server kernel: CPU: 1 PID: 1498 Comm: containerd-shim Tainted: P      D    OE     5.15.0-46-generic #49-Ubuntu
Aug 16 03:20:34 foxden-server kernel: Hardware name: Gigabyte Technology Co., Ltd. A320M-S2H/A320M-S2H-CF, BIOS F2 11/03/2020
Aug 16 03:20:34 foxden-server kernel: RIP: 0010:native_queued_spin_lock_slowpath.part.0+0x51/0x200
Aug 16 03:20:34 foxden-server kernel: Code: 2b 08 0f 92 c2 8b 03 0f b6 d2 c1 e2 08 30 e4 09 d0 a9 00 01 ff ff 0f 85 2a 01 00 00 85 c0 74 0e 8b 03 84 c0 74 08 f3 90 8b 03 <84> c0 75 f8 b8 01 00 00 00 66 89 03 5b 41 5c 41 5d 41 5e 41 5f 5d
Aug 16 03:20:34 foxden-server kernel: RSP: 0018:ffffa2eb421a3c38 EFLAGS: 00000002
Aug 16 03:20:34 foxden-server kernel: RAX: 0000000000000101 RBX: ffff8a0b96b62cc0 RCX: 0000000000000000
Aug 16 03:20:34 foxden-server kernel: RDX: 0000000000000000 RSI: 0000000000000000 RDI: ffff8a0b96b62cc0
Aug 16 03:20:34 foxden-server kernel: RBP: ffffa2eb421a3c60 R08: 0000000000000000 R09: 0000000000000000
Aug 16 03:20:34 foxden-server kernel: R10: 0000000000000000 R11: 0000000000000000 R12: 0000000000000283
Aug 16 03:20:34 foxden-server kernel: R13: ffffa2eb421a3d08 R14: ffff8a0b96b62d00 R15: 0000000000000000
Aug 16 03:20:34 foxden-server kernel: FS:  000000c000040090(0000) GS:ffff8a0b96a40000(0000) knlGS:0000000000000000
Aug 16 03:20:34 foxden-server kernel: CS:  0010 DS: 0000 ES: 0000 CR0: 0000000080050033
Aug 16 03:20:34 foxden-server kernel: CR2: 00007fecf0000020 CR3: 00000001188a0000 CR4: 00000000003506e0
Aug 16 03:20:34 foxden-server kernel: Call Trace:
Aug 16 03:20:34 foxden-server kernel:  <TASK>
Aug 16 03:20:34 foxden-server kernel:  native_queued_spin_lock_slowpath+0x2c/0x40
Aug 16 03:20:34 foxden-server kernel:  _raw_spin_lock_irqsave+0x3d/0x50
Aug 16 03:20:34 foxden-server kernel:  hrtimer_try_to_cancel.part.0+0x28/0xe0
Aug 16 03:20:34 foxden-server kernel:  hrtimer_cancel+0x21/0x40
Aug 16 03:20:34 foxden-server kernel:  futex_wait+0x232/0x260
Aug 16 03:20:34 foxden-server kernel:  ? __hrtimer_init+0x110/0x110
Aug 16 03:20:34 foxden-server kernel:  do_futex+0x149/0x1f0
Aug 16 03:20:34 foxden-server kernel:  __x64_sys_futex+0x78/0x1e0
Aug 16 03:20:34 foxden-server kernel:  do_syscall_64+0x5c/0xc0
Aug 16 03:20:34 foxden-server kernel:  ? exit_to_user_mode_prepare+0x96/0xb0
Aug 16 03:20:34 foxden-server kernel:  ? syscall_exit_to_user_mode+0x27/0x50
Aug 16 03:20:34 foxden-server kernel:  ? do_syscall_64+0x69/0xc0
Aug 16 03:20:34 foxden-server kernel:  ? syscall_exit_to_user_mode+0x27/0x50
Aug 16 03:20:34 foxden-server kernel:  ? do_syscall_64+0x69/0xc0
Aug 16 03:20:34 foxden-server kernel:  entry_SYSCALL_64_after_hwframe+0x61/0xcb
Aug 16 03:20:34 foxden-server kernel: RIP: 0033:0x465923
Aug 16 03:20:34 foxden-server kernel: Code: 24 20 c3 cc cc cc cc 48 8b 7c 24 08 8b 74 24 10 8b 54 24 14 4c 8b 54 24 18 4c 8b 44 24 20 44 8b 4c 24 28 b8 ca 00 00 00 0f 05 <89> 44 24 30 c3 cc cc cc cc cc cc cc cc cc cc cc cc cc cc cc cc cc
Aug 16 03:20:34 foxden-server kernel: RSP: 002b:000000c00004fe78 EFLAGS: 00000202 ORIG_RAX: 00000000000000ca
Aug 16 03:20:34 foxden-server kernel: RAX: ffffffffffffffda RBX: 0000000000000000 RCX: 0000000000465923
Aug 16 03:20:34 foxden-server kernel: RDX: 0000000000000000 RSI: 0000000000000080 RDI: 0000000000d27d18
Aug 16 03:20:34 foxden-server kernel: RBP: 000000c00004fec0 R08: 0000000000000000 R09: 0000000000000000
Aug 16 03:20:34 foxden-server kernel: R10: 000000c00004feb0 R11: 0000000000000202 R12: 000000c00004feb0
Aug 16 03:20:34 foxden-server kernel: R13: 000000c000040000 R14: 000000c0000004e0 R15: 00007f17589b4034
Aug 16 03:20:34 foxden-server kernel:  </TASK>
Aug 16 03:20:34 foxden-server kernel: watchdog: BUG: soft lockup - CPU#7 stuck for 22s! [runc:38715]
Aug 16 03:20:34 foxden-server kernel: Modules linked in: tls rfcomm xt_connmark xt_mark iptable_mangle xt_comment iptable_raw iptable_nat wireguard curve25519_x86_64 libchacha20poly1305 chacha_x86_64 poly1305_x86_64 libblake2s blake2s_x86_64 libcurve25519_generic libchacha libblake2s_generic ip6_udp_tunnel udp_tunnel iptable_filter bpfilter xt_nat xt_tcpudp veth xt_conntrack nft_chain_nat xt_MASQUERADE nf_nat nf_conntrack_netlink nf_conntrack nf_defrag_ipv6 nf_defrag_ipv4 xfrm_user xfrm_algo nft_counter xt_addrtype nft_compat nf_tables nfnetlink br_netfilter bridge stp llc cmac algif_hash algif_skcipher af_alg bnep overlay nls_iso8859_1 snd_hda_codec_realtek snd_hda_codec_generic intel_rapl_msr intel_rapl_common snd_hda_codec_hdmi ledtrig_audio snd_hda_intel snd_intel_dspcfg snd_intel_sdw_acpi edac_mce_amd snd_hda_codec kvm_amd snd_hda_core snd_hwdep btusb nvidiafb snd_pcm btrtl btbcm btintel snd_timer snd bluetooth ecdh_generic ecc soundcore k10temp nvidia_uvm(POE) vgastate ccp fb_ddc i2c_algo_bit kvm rapl
Aug 16 03:20:34 foxden-server kernel:  gigabyte_wmi wmi_bmof mac_hid sch_fq_codel ledtrig_timer ipmi_devintf dm_multipath ipmi_msghandler scsi_dh_rdac mtd scsi_dh_emc scsi_dh_alua msr efi_pstore ramoops pstore_blk reed_solomon pstore_zone ip_tables x_tables autofs4 btrfs blake2b_generic zstd_compress raid10 raid456 async_raid6_recov async_memcpy async_pq async_xor async_tx xor raid6_pq libcrc32c raid1 raid0 multipath linear nvidia_drm(POE) nvidia_modeset(POE) nvidia(POE) drm_kms_helper syscopyarea crct10dif_pclmul sysfillrect crc32_pclmul sysimgblt ghash_clmulni_intel fb_sys_fops cec aesni_intel rc_core crypto_simd r8169 ahci xhci_pci gpio_amdpt cryptd drm i2c_piix4 realtek libahci xhci_pci_renesas wmi gpio_generic
Aug 16 03:20:34 foxden-server kernel: CPU: 7 PID: 38715 Comm: runc Tainted: P      D    OE     5.15.0-46-generic #49-Ubuntu
Aug 16 03:20:34 foxden-server kernel: Hardware name: Gigabyte Technology Co., Ltd. A320M-S2H/A320M-S2H-CF, BIOS F2 11/03/2020
Aug 16 03:20:34 foxden-server kernel: RIP: 0010:smp_call_function_single+0x94/0x120
Aug 16 03:20:34 foxden-server kernel: Code: 17 29 54 a9 00 01 ff 00 0f 85 97 00 00 00 85 c9 75 46 48 c7 c6 c0 1a 03 00 65 48 03 35 55 b1 28 54 8b 46 08 a8 01 74 09 f3 90 <8b> 46 08 a8 01 75 f7 83 4e 08 01 4c 89 46 10 48 89 56 18 e8 54 fe
Aug 16 03:20:34 foxden-server kernel: RSP: 0018:ffffa2eb42a0faa0 EFLAGS: 00000202
Aug 16 03:20:34 foxden-server kernel: RAX: 0000000000000001 RBX: 0000001c241b1fcd RCX: 0000000000000000
Aug 16 03:20:34 foxden-server kernel: RDX: 0000000000000000 RSI: ffff8a0b96bf1ac0 RDI: 0000000000000007
Aug 16 03:20:34 foxden-server kernel: RBP: ffffa2eb42a0faf0 R08: ffffffffabc597f0 R09: 0000000000000000
Aug 16 03:20:34 foxden-server kernel: R10: 0000000000000007 R11: ffffffffffffff80 R12: 000000000001fbe0
Aug 16 03:20:34 foxden-server kernel: R13: 0000000000000007 R14: ffff8a0b96bc0000 R15: 0000000000000007
Aug 16 03:20:34 foxden-server kernel: FS:  00007f735c30c740(0000) GS:ffff8a0b96bc0000(0000) knlGS:0000000000000000
Aug 16 03:20:34 foxden-server kernel: CS:  0010 DS: 0000 ES: 0000 CR0: 0000000080050033
Aug 16 03:20:34 foxden-server kernel: CR2: 0000560bf5250420 CR3: 000000010953a000 CR4: 00000000003506e0
Aug 16 03:20:34 foxden-server kernel: Call Trace:
Aug 16 03:20:34 foxden-server kernel:  <TASK>
Aug 16 03:20:34 foxden-server kernel:  ? pick_link+0x27f/0x3f0
Aug 16 03:20:34 foxden-server kernel:  ? set_pte+0x9/0x20
Aug 16 03:20:34 foxden-server kernel:  aperfmperf_snapshot_cpu+0x83/0xe0
Aug 16 03:20:34 foxden-server kernel:  ? recalibrate_cpu_khz+0x10/0x10
Aug 16 03:20:34 foxden-server kernel:  arch_freq_prepare_all+0x74/0xc0
Aug 16 03:20:34 foxden-server kernel:  ? proc_reg_read+0xa0/0xa0
Aug 16 03:20:34 foxden-server kernel:  cpuinfo_open+0x13/0x30
Aug 16 03:20:34 foxden-server kernel:  proc_reg_open+0x3b/0x160
Aug 16 03:20:34 foxden-server kernel:  ? proc_reg_read+0xa0/0xa0
Aug 16 03:20:34 foxden-server kernel:  do_dentry_open+0x159/0x390
Aug 16 03:20:34 foxden-server kernel:  vfs_open+0x2d/0x40
Aug 16 03:20:34 foxden-server kernel:  do_open+0x20d/0x3d0
Aug 16 03:20:34 foxden-server kernel:  path_openat+0x112/0x2b0
Aug 16 03:20:34 foxden-server kernel:  ? filename_lookup+0xcf/0x1d0
Aug 16 03:20:34 foxden-server kernel:  do_filp_open+0xb2/0x160
Aug 16 03:20:34 foxden-server kernel:  ? __check_object_size+0x1d/0x30
Aug 16 03:20:34 foxden-server kernel:  do_sys_openat2+0x9f/0x160
Aug 16 03:20:34 foxden-server kernel:  __x64_sys_openat+0x55/0x90
Aug 16 03:20:34 foxden-server kernel:  do_syscall_64+0x5c/0xc0
Aug 16 03:20:34 foxden-server kernel:  ? exit_to_user_mode_prepare+0x37/0xb0
Aug 16 03:20:34 foxden-server kernel:  ? syscall_exit_to_user_mode+0x27/0x50
Aug 16 03:20:34 foxden-server kernel:  ? __x64_sys_newfstatat+0x1c/0x30
Aug 16 03:20:34 foxden-server kernel:  ? do_syscall_64+0x69/0xc0
Aug 16 03:20:34 foxden-server kernel:  ? exit_to_user_mode_prepare+0x37/0xb0
Aug 16 03:20:34 foxden-server kernel:  ? irqentry_exit_to_user_mode+0x9/0x20
Aug 16 03:20:34 foxden-server kernel:  ? irqentry_exit+0x1d/0x30
Aug 16 03:20:34 foxden-server kernel:  ? exc_page_fault+0x89/0x170
Aug 16 03:20:34 foxden-server kernel:  entry_SYSCALL_64_after_hwframe+0x61/0xcb
Aug 16 03:20:34 foxden-server kernel: RIP: 0033:0x560bf4fdbdca
Aug 16 03:20:34 foxden-server kernel: Code: e8 1b 74 fb ff 48 8b 7c 24 10 48 8b 74 24 18 48 8b 54 24 20 4c 8b 54 24 28 4c 8b 44 24 30 4c 8b 4c 24 38 48 8b 44 24 08 0f 05 <48> 3d 01 f0 ff ff 76 20 48 c7 44 24 40 ff ff ff ff 48 c7 44 24 48
Aug 16 03:20:34 foxden-server kernel: RSP: 002b:000000c0001bf060 EFLAGS: 00000202 ORIG_RAX: 0000000000000101
Aug 16 03:20:34 foxden-server kernel: RAX: ffffffffffffffda RBX: 000000c000035000 RCX: 0000560bf4fdbdca
Aug 16 03:20:34 foxden-server kernel: RDX: 0000000000080000 RSI: 000000c00012f202 RDI: ffffffffffffff9c
Aug 16 03:20:34 foxden-server kernel: RBP: 000000c0001bf0f0 R08: 0000000000000000 R09: 0000000000000000
Aug 16 03:20:34 foxden-server kernel: R10: 0000000000000000 R11: 0000000000000202 R12: 000000c00012f200
Aug 16 03:20:34 foxden-server kernel: R13: 0000000000000000 R14: 000000c0000001a0 R15: 00007f73357a594f
Aug 16 03:20:34 foxden-server kernel:  </TASK>
```

Comment: Its a stock Ubuntu server install without a desktop environment.

Comment: Developers like to log every piddling little issue, so nothing in the logs suggests a hardware problem instead of an Ubuntu issue. You already checked RAM, next run a SMART test on your storage devices. And, if possible, try a different power supply. Those are three most common hardware failures.

Comment: 1st gen ryzen had problems in Linux. Look up online for BIOS updates (warning: some motherboards drop support for 1st gen CPUs to make room for 3rd gen; make sure to read the notes of all versions between your current & latest before installing latest BIOS update). Also rule out RAM problems first

Comment: See https://bugzilla.kernel.org/show_bug.cgi?id=196683